# CGRect in Pixels?

Tags: objective-c, ios, size, pixel, cgrect

Pretty much I want to properly have the size of a button in my app converted to the amount of pixels for its width and height.

So lets say it has a width of 50 and a height of 100, on a retina display device I want it to return a width of 100 and a height of 200. On a non-retina device it should return a width of 50 and a height of 100.

And it should work the same way on the iPad. Anyway, how would I do this? Would I use the UIScreen's mainScreen scale, or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you put on the screen in measured in points, not pixels. A non-retina iPhone is 320x480 points. A retina-iPhone (3.5") is 320x480 points.

This is true on all devices. Don't worry about pixels, worry about points.

- 320x480 (3.5" iPhones/iPod touches)
- 320x568 (4" iPhones/iPod touches)
- 768x1024 (iPads - all)

Your button would be measured as 100x50 on all devices.

Update:

When working with images you need to create two sets of images.

- image.png would be the "normal" size of say 100x50
- image@2x.png would be the "retina" size of 200x100

By providing the two images, the OS grabs the proper one. Your code still measures everything in points. So the 200x100 retina image will be shown as 100x50 points on a retina device.

Comment: The reason I worry about pixels is because I resize an UIImage to the size of the rect of my UIButton. So if I just do that, my image will look blurry on Retina devices because I am missing half the resolution it should be.

Comment: I see so the only way to do this is just to create multiple images? Right now I just have one BIG image and resize it based upon the rect of the button. I don't understand why I can't use UIScreen's scale property in this scenario. It would reduce the number of assets and it would work on all devices properly wouldn't it?.

Comment: @iBradApps This is the way it is done. We all bundle two sets of images with our apps. The benefit is there is no scaling or stretching. You have one set of retina images that look good on retina devices and one set of images for non-retina that look good on non-retina devices.

Comment: Okay so lets say my button is an exact square, 100x100. In that case could I do UIScreen's .scale? Do you disapprove of using the .scale because of a programmatically problem or a UI issue?

Comment: You don't need the scale. Make your button 100x100. That's it. You provide two images - one that is 100x100 and the other that is 200x200. The OS will pick the right one for you. But the button is 100x100 on all devices. No scale is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the previous answer in that you should generally ship two sets of assets instead of resizing one on runtime, you can still do that.

Scaling an UIImage to the correct scale of the screen would indeed mean using UIScreen's scale property. However in future interests it might make more sense not to use `[UIScreen mainScreen]`, but instead determine the view the image will get displayed in and obtain the screen from there.

All in all, it would probably make more sense to not mess around with creating a separate image, and letting the OS handle its' own scaling. If you know the asset is @2x you could use `+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale` to create the object and define the scale in there, this way the system will know the scale and will handle the resizing properly even if displayed on a @1x screen.